# OpenCVを用いたC++のプログラムで、"識別子 CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE , CV_WINDOW_FREERATIO が定義されていません" とエラーが出る

Tags: c++, opencv

OpenCV 4.0.0とVisualStudio c++ を使用して、以下のサンプルプログラムを実行したいのですが、33行目の

```
CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE | CV_WINDOW_FREERATIO
```

という部分でそれぞれ

```
識別子”CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE” ”CV_WINDOW_FREERATIO” が定義されていません。
```

とエラーが出てきます。試しに`cv＿`と打ち込んで予測変換から似たものを探しましたがありませんでした。`cv::namedWindow`のユーザーインターフェイスを使用するためには何か別の処理が必要なのでしょうか？
このバージョンでは使用できないのでしょうか？また、同じ意味のコードがあれば教えて欲しいです。

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

#if defined _DEBUG
#define CV_EXT "d.lib"
#else
#define CV_EXT ".lib"
#endif

#pragma comment(lib, "opencv_core2413" CV_EXT)
#pragma comment(lib, "opencv_imgproc2413" CV_EXT)
#pragma comment(lib, "opencv_highgui2413" CV_EXT)

int main()
{
cv::Mat srcImg = cv::imread("lenna.jpg");
if (srcImg.empty())
return 1;

cv::namedWindow("image", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE | CV_WINDOW_FREERATIO);
cv::imshow("image", srcImg);
cv::waitKey();

return 0;
}
```

Comment: 英語版SOでの関連質問 - [where can I find CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE constants?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18682201/2322778)

Comment: cv::WINDOW_AUTOSIZEにしたら出来ました。

Comment: SOでは自己回答も歓迎ですので、解決に至った情報を残してもらうと他のユーザの助けになると思います。併せて、質問のタイトルは質問内容が分かるような文言になっているとより親切です(後からでも [編集] できます)。

Answer (score 2):

[`CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.0.0-alpha/d0/d28/group__highgui__c.html#enum-members)はC言語向けのC APIです。C++言語では[`cv::WINDOW_AUTOSIZE`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.0.0-alpha/d7/dfc/group__highgui.html#enum-members)を使う必要があります。